# The field is not visible?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having trouble running this program that tests for inheritance in java. I made two classes, one Drink class that is supposed to be the parent class, and one tea class that is supposed to be the child class. I made a constructor that calls to the parent constructor with super() in order to create a new tea object. However, the compiler is telling me that the field for one of the parameters I am sending in (caloriesPerOunce) is not visible. Even though I didn't require the parameter to be included in the constructor for Tea(), I did declare and instantiate it later in the block. Is this an issue with my code or is there something in the settings I should change since I am using an eclipse IDE?

```java
public class Drink {
    private String name;
    private double quantity;
    private int caloriesPerOunce;
    
    public Drink(String name, double quantity, int caloriesPerOunce)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.caloriesPerOunce = caloriesPerOunce;
    }
```

```java
public class Tea extends Drink{
    private boolean isSweet;
    public Tea(String name, double quantity, boolean isSweet)
    {
        super(name, quantity, caloriesPerOunce); //here it tells me that the field Drink.caloriesPerOunce is not visble
        int caloriesPerOunce = 100;
        this.isSweet = isSweet;
    }
```

Comment: What should `super(name, quantity, caloriesPerOunce);` achieve in your specific case? `caloriesPerOunce` should be replaced by whatever calories a tea has because there's no such variable defined in `Tea`

Answer (score 1):

**Java is not JavaScript**
Short answer: Stop pretending that Java is JavaScript.

Longer answer:
In this code:

```
super(name, quantity, caloriesPerOunce);
int caloriesPerOunce = 100;
```

You are 100% attempting to access the parent `caloriesPerOunce` variable.
This is because you do not declare the local `caloriesPerOunce` until after the `super` "call".
In Java (unlike JavaScript) there is no hoisting of variables to the top of scope.

If you want to pass 100 to the parent constructor, then pass 100 to the parent constructor.

```
super(name, quantity, 100);
```

If 100 is a constant value for Tea,
then you can declare a "constant" field for the class and pass the "constant" field.
For example,

```
private static final int TEA_CALORIES = 100;

public Tea(String name, double quantity, boolean isSweet)
{
    super(name, quality, TEA_CALORIES);

    ... other stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tea class constructor has no argument named `caloriesPerOunce`. Are you trying to access the variable from the `Drink` parent class then that wont work since the scope of `caloriesPerOunce` is private. The `caloriesPerOunce` variable could be accessed if the classes are nested then why use inheritance?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html